# action init hook and get_post_types

Tags: custom-post-types, actions

Why if I register a custom post type by `add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type' )` hook it doesn't show in returned array by `get_post_types` function?
Example:

```
function test(){
    $args = array(
            'public'          => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'         => true,
            'query_var'       => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => true,
            'hierarchical'    => false,
            'has_archive'     => false,

        ); 

        register_post_type( 'test', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'test' );
print_r(get_post_types()); 
Array
(
    [post] => post
    [page] => page
    [attachment] => attachment
    [revision] => revision
    [nav_menu_item] => nav_menu_item
    //no test post type in array
)
```

but if I just run function `test()` the post type `test` appears in `get_post_type` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you calling get_post_types() in functions.php that is excuted before 'init' action.
Look this picture http://www.rarst.net/images/wordpress_core_load.png

if you add an echo inside function test

```
function test(){
    $args = array(
        'public'          => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'         => true,
        'query_var'       => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'hierarchical'    => false,
        'has_archive'     => false,

    ); 

    register_post_type( 'test', $args );

    echo 'HELLO!!';

}
add_action( 'init', 'test' );

print_r(get_post_types());
```

You'll see before the array of custom fields and then 'Hello!" string!

Comment: So what you can recommend me to fix this problem? How is the best way to register custom post type?

Comment: @user853543: I suppose you didn't see my answer. I said exactly the same a few minutes before you.

Comment: I saw it after that I published my comment! I'm sorry!

Comment: @MichałKalkowski you can try to change the hook `add_action( 'init', 'test' );` to `add_action( 'setup_theme', 'test' );`

Comment: @kream no this doesn't work the custom post type isn't registerd.

Comment: yeap.. we can add_action with hook setup_theme only in plugin.. :(
Where do you need to use get_post_types()?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are executing `get_post_types()` before the post type is registered. Try, for example, this:

```
function test(){
    $args = array(
        'public'          => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'         => true,
        'query_var'       => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'hierarchical'    => false,
        'has_archive'     => false,

    ); 

    register_post_type( 'test', $args );

    print_r(get_post_types());

}
add_action( 'init', 'test' );
```

Similar results you will get if you call `get_post_types()` in your template or any other situation that come after the Wordpress `init` event.