# get_post_types() can't get some of my post type

Tags: custom-post-types, php

I want to get all post types filtered by get_post_types() arguments.

```
public static function get_post_type()
{
    if(!$post_type = wp_cache_get('post_type', 'dsad'))
    {
        $post_type = get_post_types(array(
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true
        ));
        wp_cache_set('post_type', $post_type, 'dsad');
    }

    return $post_type;
}
```

However, with this code, it returns this value:

```
array(3) {
  ["post"]=>
  string(4) "post"
  ["page"]=>
  string(4) "page"
  ["attachment"]=>
  string(10) "attachment"
}
```

How can I get all of my post types?

Comment: You need to run it after the other post types have been registered. When are you running this code?

Comment: caching the value of `get_post_types()` doesn't speed things up, there's no database query involved, and post types are registered on every page load so that information is already in memory

Answer (score 1):

Build in WordPress function for fetching all registered post types: **get_post_types()**

```
    <?php
    // hook into init late, so everything is registered
    // you can also use get_post_types where ever.  Any time after init is usually fine.
    add_action( 'init', 'wpse34410_init', 0, 99 );
    function wpse34410_init() 
    {
        $types = get_post_types( [], 'objects' );
        foreach ( $types as $type ) {
            if ( isset( $type->rewrite->slug ) ) {
                // you'll probably want to do something else.
                echo $type->rewrite->slug;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer can give you an important advice: [action init hook and get_post_types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139403/action-init-hook-and-get-post-types)

you've to run your function using an hook later than `init` which is likely the hook used to register your CPT 
So I think:

```
add_action('wp_loaded', 'get_post_type');
function get_post_type()
{
    if(!$post_type = wp_cache_get('post_type', 'dsad'))
    {
        $post_type = get_post_types(array(
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true
        ));
        wp_cache_set('post_type', $post_type, 'dsad');
    }

    return $post_type;
}
```

will work